# How to describe a puppet show

Tags: word-choice

I want to describe a puppet show we saw. It was in a theatre and performed by professional puppeteers. I found three terms for puppet: 人形, 木偶, and 傀儡. I couldn't find anything for puppeteer.

Here's my wild guess at saying, "We saw a puppet show. The puppeteers were from Taiwan."

我们一起去看木偶戏剧。木偶者是台湾人。

Comment: Yes, there doesn't seem to be a word for putteteer. Before I've seen people use 操纵木偶的人.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "puppet show" can be called [木偶戏](http://baike.baidu.com/view/51751.htm), [木偶剧, 傀儡戲、人偶戲、or 人偶劇](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%A8%E5%81%B6%E5%8A%87) .

You can refer specifically to a puppeteer as 操纵木偶者 or simply (遮蔽)操纵者. But to refer to puppeteers in general, I feel that 操纵木偶的艺人(们) would be more appropriate.

So for your phrase, one way of saying it would be 我们去看了一个木偶戏/剧。操纵木偶的艺人们是从台湾来的。

Comment: Thanks, my teacher was really impressed with the vocabulary when I gave my presentation, so I confessed that I had help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps 操偶師 ?

It literally means "the master who controls the puppet."

Comment: Doesn't seem to be used in mainland China.

Comment: @JamesJiao Actually it's okay, but most used in formal occasion or in writting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and welcome to the Chinese Language Stack Exchange site.